# jQuery noConflict and function not defined

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to get this to work and have looked around at different Q&A's regarding jQuery noConflict() and haven't found a solution that works for my situation. If it has been answered somewhere else I apologize.

I'm using prototype.js and googles jquery 1.7.2 and have a script that looks like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict(); 
(function($){

function nextPage(value){
 //Some code
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  nextPage('some value'); // Loads on doc ready

  //Some other code
});

})(jQuery);
```

I need to be able to call the nextPage() function again after everything is loaded from the click of a button however after wrapping it with the noConflict() its not available. It gives me the error "ReferenceError: nextPage is not defined"

How do I define it or what do I need to do to make this function available again after everything has loaded? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should call it from inside closure otherwise inside this function, $ will not reference jQuery, of course if you are using $ inside nextPage() function

Comment: Yea im using $ inside the nextPage function it works as is except when I click the next button to load the next page it gave me that error.

Comment: So you cannot called it from outside closure scope or use `jQuery` inside nextPage() but not `$`

Comment: I havent tried using jQuery('#someid').click(function(){}); within the nextPage function having it outside the scope. If I understand you correctly?

Comment: Looks like you understand me correctly

Comment: Seems that there should be a better way considering if you a large amount of code in a function this would mean you would have to change all $ to jQuery. Kinda of ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your function outside of the closure.

```
function nextPage(value) {
    //Some code
}

jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) {


    $(document).ready(function () {

        nextPage('some value'); // Loads on doc ready

        //Some other code
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Doing that seems to break the script.

Comment: This moves `nextPage()` outside the closure and thus it can't use the `$` that is defined inside the closure and may not be able to use the right version of jQuery (if there are multiple versions).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  A. Wolff I was able to get it working by doing the following:

```
jQuery.noConflict(); 
(function($){

function nextPage(value){
//Some code

// Use jQuery here not $
jQuery('#editButton').removeClass('green_btn');

}

// Use $ here
$(document).ready(function(){

nextPage('some value'); // Loads on doc ready

//Some other code
$('#someid').click();
});

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have your button click event handler inside the same closure that `nextPage()` is defined in.  That gives it access to all the variables and function defined within the closure.

```
jQuery.noConflict(); 
(function($){

function nextPage(value){
 //Some code
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  nextPage('some value'); // Loads on doc ready

  //Some other code
});

// define your click handler here
// and it can then access everything within the enclosed function block
// including the nextPage() function
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    // do other stuff
    nextPage();
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I will try this method as well but for now it it working. Thanks!